# Writing dataframe partitions to custom directory in scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a dataframe with millions of records and need to partition the data into s3 bucket folders less than 200MB or 200,000 rows using a glue job. Using partitionBy won't work because there is no column value that splits the data in a way that keeps the partitions below the size we need for some downstream processes. I tried adding monotonically increasing id and writing based on a predefined range of id but that won't work because monotonically_increasing_id is not consecutive. How do I get a glue job to write partitioned data into s3 folders of less than 200mb or is there a way to partitionBy a repartitioned dataframe

```
    val newdf = diffDF.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())                    
    var batchSize = 100000
    var totalRecordCount = diffDF.count()
    var currentRow = 0        
         while(currentRow < totalRecordCount){
             var segmentDF = newdf.where(col("id") >= currentRow and col("id") < (currentRow + batchSize ))
                                   .drop("id")
             segmentDF.write.option("header","true").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv(tpath + "/" + currentRow)
             currentRow = currentRow + batchSize
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding a column that was a remainder of the division of the id values.

```
val diffDF = .withColumn("partitionnum", col("Employee_ID") % 9) .write.option("header","true").partitionBy("partitionnum").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv(tpath)
```

This will give 9 partitions and is highly customizable. you can divide by 5 for 5 partitions etc

Answer (score 0):

This is a Scala-ish solution, that uses folding, I tried adapting the same logic into spark, and the most similar thing that spark rdd's have right now, is `rdd.aggregate`, which the combineOp in its parameter list just ruins everything! So if you feel comfortable using `RDD`s, this approach or something similar in spark would work for you:

```scala
val rdd = df.rdd
rdd.collect().foldLeft(List.empty[List[Row]]) {
    case (l@(headAggregator :: tail), newRow) =>
      // this if represents rdd size, so instead of list.length you can capture rdd size
      if ((newRow :: headAggregator).length < 3) (newRow :: headAggregator)  :: tail
      else (newRow :: Nil) :: l
    case (Nil, newRow) =>
      (newRow :: Nil) :: Nil
  }
```

I know, this `rdd.collect()` is very expensive actually, but I just implemented the logic, so if you found something similar to foldLeft for `RDD`s, just copy and paste the function body :)